# Server timeout error - Emulator can connect to local web services but not the device

Tags: android, web-services

New to Android, I have .Net webservices residing in my PC. when my Android application calls the webservice from emulator with IP address, it runs perfectly.

But running the same code in mobile does not work (mobile is connected to PC using USB cable). It shows server timeout error. Both phone and PC are on the same network.

[image]

I am unable to run - adb pull /data/anr/traces.txt. It says unrecognized command. I had Android studio installed but unable to find adb file.

So installed Android Sdk again: C:\Program Files\android-sdk-windows\tools - it says that adb file has moved to platform-tools. I tried various ways but no luck.

Any suggestions are welcome. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your web service is not hosted, you need to use localhost or 127.0.0.1 in your mobile app's URL IP address. Make sure they are in the same network

Comment: This does not work. Only my own IP address is working.

Comment: There can be an exception of Firewall. By default firewall does not allow incoming and outgoing HTTP traffic. Allow firewall to accept income and outgoing HTTP request.

Comment: I do not have any firewall.